# PHP exec() does return nothing. Problem with whoami

Tags: php, python, cmd, exec

I want to call a python file with the exec() command from PHP.

```
exec("$python_exe $python_script", $output);
echo $output;
```

The python file simply returns a string 'Hello'. When I run the php script from the exec function it returns nothing. I tried running the command from cmd and it works. After following some discussions I analyzed the result of command `whoami`. On cmd, it returns `<computer-name>\<user-name>` instead of php returns `nt authority system`. I tried to change the service properties of Apache from "Local System" to another user / account from service.msc (the user / account is the same of cmd). But does not work.

I checked also into php.ini `disable_functions`, but the problem in not here. (disable_functions no have value).

`$python_exe` = Absolute path to python.exe.

`$python_script` = Absolute pathto python script.

`safe_mode` = off. (php.ini)

Any suggestion? thx.

Comment: How do you execute the script? Also via CLI? Or via php-fpm?

Comment: If i execute the script with the command line work.

Comment: `exec` returns an array, if you want to print use `var_dump` instead of `echo`

Comment: tried dont works. The problem is nt authority system but i can not resolve it